# CustomListViewAddapter in Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with CustomListViewAddapter in Fragment. 
I have main activity which has slide menu and I try to show a CustomListView in it. 
and I get this error when I tried to use try-catch

here is part of my main activity that call fragment from slide menu

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")public class MainActivity extends Activity {
.......Some Code.....

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void displayView(int position) {
    Log.i("Position***", position + "");
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Fragment fragment1 = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        fragment1 = fragment;
        Log.i("fragment1", fragment1 + "");
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }

}
SOme Code
}
```

he is my HomeFragment.java

```
 public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener {
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


}



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View fragProcatView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,false);


        MainListView = (ListView) fragProcatView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        /*
         * ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
         * full-screen list in the center of the screen. However,we can
         * customize the screen layout by setting our own view layout with
         * setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, our layout MUST contain a
         * ListView object with the id "@android:id/list". ( NOT
         * android:id="@+id/list" ). if we define a ListView with the android:id
         * attribute set to @+id/list then it will throw below RuntimeException
         */

        dataSource = new ETPUPDataSource(getActivity());

        dataSource.open();
        addedETPUP = dataSource.getAllRecordList();
        dataSource.close();

        Log.i("DBCount", addedETPUP.size() + "");
        // if this is first time that we run App so maybe we dont have any data
        // on it so we need to check that
        // And call our list View again
        if (addedETPUP.size() == 0) {
            if (InternetStatus.getInstance(getActivity()).haveNetworkConnection(getActivity())) {
                Log.i("XXXX return haveConnectedWifi", "return haveConnectedWifiXXXX");
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alertBuilder.setMessage("There Is No Dara To Show. Do You Want To Add New Data?");
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                // Call Json To Get Data From Server

                                new JSONParse().execute();
                                refreshList();

                            }

                        });

                alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        "There Is No Internet Connection Available, Please Make Sure Your Device Connected To InterNet Via WIFI Or Mobile Internet!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        // Create New object from your CustomListViewAddapter and pass this
        // context and your list of ETPUP as data


        try{
            ArrayAdapter<getAllData> adapterMain = new CustomListViewAddapter(getActivity(), addedETPUP);
            MainListView.setAdapter(adapterMain);

            //MainListView.setAdapter(new CustomListViewAddapter(getActivity(), addedETPUP));
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Error Happened ", "During creating List view");
            Log.e("Error Happened ", e.toString());
        }

        // registerForContextMenu(MainListView.getListView());

        BtnGetData = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        BtnGetData.setOnClickListener(this);  

        btnShowFav = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.ShowFav);
        btnShowFav.setOnClickListener(this); 


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }









@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.getdata:

        new JSONParse().execute();

    case R.id.ShowFav:
        Log.i("show Fav", "in show Fav btn");
        Intent ShowFav = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowFavorite.class);
        startActivity(ShowFav);

        break;
    }
}

public void refreshList() {
    Log.i("Refresh List", "I'm in Refresh List");

    // Create New object from your CustomListViewAddapter and pass this
    // context and your list of ETPUP as data
    dataSource.open();
    addedETPUP = dataSource.getAllRecordList();
    dataSource.close();

    Log.i("DBCount*****00******", addedETPUP.size() + "");

    try{
    ArrayAdapter<getAllData> adapterMain = new CustomListViewAddapter(getActivity(), addedETPUP);
    MainListView.setAdapter(adapterMain);

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Error Happened In Refresh", "During creating List view");
        Log.e("Error Happened ", e.toString());
    }
    // registerForContextMenu(((ListActivity) MainListView).getListView());

    // This Just Show Simple List

    /*
     * ArrayAdapter<getAllData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<getAllData>(this,
     * android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,addedZekrFields2);
     * setListAdapter(adapter); registerForContextMenu(getListView());
     */
}
```

and here is my Log Cat

```
06-01 23:24:38.861: D/dalvikvm(1873): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 96K, 6% free 3142K/3308K, paused 30ms, total 32ms
Blockquote

06-01 23:24:38.871: I/dalvikvm-heap(1873): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.207MB for 1127536-byte allocation

06-01 23:24:38.911: D/dalvikvm(1873): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 4240K/4412K, paused 31ms, total 31ms

06-01 23:24:39.021: I/Position***(1873): 2

06-01 23:24:39.331: D/gralloc_goldfish(1873): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

06-01 23:24:42.801: I/in Draw Click***(1873): 000000000000011123

06-01 23:24:42.801: I/Position***(1873): 0

06-01 23:24:42.811: I/fragment1(1873): HomeFragment{b1f98308}

06-01 23:24:43.061: D/dalvikvm(1873): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 80K, 4% free 4657K/4816K, paused 24ms, total 29ms

06-01 23:24:43.121: I/ETPUP(1873): Database open

06-01 23:24:43.141: I/ETPUP(1873): Database close

06-01 23:24:43.141: I/DBCount(1873): 3

06-01 23:24:43.161: E/Error Happened(1873): During creating List view

06-01 23:24:43.161: E/Error Happened(1873): java.lang.NullPointerException

06-01 23:24:43.161: D/AndroidRuntime(1873): Shutting down VM

06-01 23:24:43.161: W/dalvikvm(1873): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
(group=0xb1b08ba8)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): Process: com.PishgamanIt.ETPUP, PID: 1873

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): java.lang.NullPointerException

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.PishgamanIt.ETPUP.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:171)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

06-01 23:24:43.181: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

06-01 23:29:43.301: I/Process(1873): Sending signal. PID: 1873 SIG: 9
```

here is my main xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" 
    />
```

and here is my fragment_home.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout1111111111111"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/getdata"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getdata"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ShowFav"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ShowFav"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list"
        android:text="Get Data" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ShowFav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Show Favorites" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I did a lot of researches and I'm stuck here for almost a week :(

I really appricate any help and advice

Comment: Post your `fragment_home.xml`

Comment: I just added my main and frgment xml
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: **No One?** :( 
Please if you have any idea for this problem, provide it 
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First correct this you should

```
return fragProcatView;
```

instead of

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
```

in `onCreateView(.....)` in your `HomeFragment`

### Update:

First remove `ListFragment` and extends a simple `Fragment` to your `HomeFragment`

your should change this `android:id="@android:id/list"` to `android:id="@+id/list"`

and then you should change this

```
    BtnGetData = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.getdata)
    btnShowFav = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.ShowFav);
```

to

```
    BtnGetData = (Button) fragProcatView.findViewById(R.id.getdata)
    btnShowFav = (Button) fragProcatView.findViewById(R.id.ShowFav);
```

Comment: I did it before. but no luck :(

Comment: it seems this error happen when it try to create custom list view.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: @mrsh hi remove `ListFragment` and Extends a `Simple Fragment`

Comment: No luck :( .
I still get what I put in try catch.
`Log.e("Error Happened ", "During creating List view");
Log.e("Error Happened ", e.toString());`
I made some changes and my App doesn't crash anymore but, it stucked in try-catch :( .
Last but not least I had same problem even if I use ListFragment.

Comment: now it's crashed :(
`06-05 00:16:21.697: E/AndroidRuntime(2480): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView`
is it related to this 
`MainListView = (ListView) fragProcatView.findViewById(R.id.list);`
I didn't cast list view to btn anywhere?

Comment: @mrsh you also change this  `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/list"` to your `ShowFav Button`. I must tell you one thing you just copy-paste this code from some where and you go wrong every where.

Comment: ok, no crash anymore, I also can see two btn but, no list view :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55107/discussion-between-simple-plan-and-m-r-sh).

Comment: I really peripatetic your help. can we continue this discussion in chat? do you have time for that?